# Where to take Project class if developing Gradle plugin as standalone?

Tags: gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

I am trying to create standalone Gradle plugin as described here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#N1464B

Unfortunately authors does not show what is seem to them as being common.

Particularly, they don't say where to take `Project` class. If I write

```
import org.gradle.api.Project

class GreetingPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

}
```

I get

> Groovyc: unable to resolve class org.gradle.api.Project

How to fix?

**UPDATE**

build file:

```
group MYGROUP
version MYVERSION

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'

    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()

}
```

the project is a module of upper project.

**UPDATE**

I have the following structure:

```
parentproject/
  src/main/java/
     ..java files..
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
  thisproject/
    src/main/groovy/..package../GreetingSupport.groovy
    build.gradle
```

I would like to develop Gradle plugin in `thisproject` and then use it in `parentproject`, which is normal Java project.

Comment: You have the dependencies `compile gradleApi()` and `compile localGroovy()` in your build.gradle like in the docs you link to yeah?  What's the structure of your code?

Comment: Yes I have. What is the "structure of code"? Code file is posted completely, and I will post build file now...

Comment: Where have you stuck your source code?

Comment: And you could really do with putting it in a package if you haven't

Comment: @tim_yates see my update please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I [tried to find out how to do this a few weeks ago](https://twitter.com/tim_yates/status/701097135555670018), and found there are 3 options for writing a plugin:

1) Put your plugin inside `buildSrc`, ie:

```
project
  |-buildSrc
  |   |-src
  |   |   \-main
  |   |       \-java
  |   |            - your.package.YourPlugin.java
  |   \-build.gradle
  |-src
  |   \-main
  |       \-java
  |            - another.package.SomeCode.java
  \-build.gradle
```

2) Write a separate project with the plugin in, publish it locally, and pull this in to your project like a normal project

3) Do it like you are trying, [with some fancy hacks](https://gist.github.com/johnrengelman/9a20697b2246a9bfaca2) in the `buildSrc/build.gradle` file to get it to load out of a project in the root folder

I went with 1) as it was easier to get up and running, and felt like it was going to work in future versions of Gradle (as it's one of their documented ways)